# JavaScript Form Validation for Textarea with Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, textarea

How would I implement error checking of multiple values entered into a textarea? I need to make sure that the values entered use commas as a delimiter before the form is submitted.

Comment: what kind of data you are looking for in the textarea? numbers or strings?

Comment: Are you trying to check to see if a `textarea` contains a CSV?

Comment: Numbers like 5,1,2,4. They need to be separated by a comma, and I forgot to mention there needs to be 4 or less of the numbers in each string. 5+ numbers would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`value.split(",")`

to separate each word and individually validate them and

`value.split(",").length < 2`

to check if commas were entered. Should be good to get you started.

Update: I have update the fiddle with your new inputs. It includes check for empty inputs before or after comma, and it trims out spaces before validation

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hbhsaros/4/)

Comment: Is that code going to loop through each string and checking them one by one upon clicking the submit button?

Comment: No its being checked on click of button

Comment: If you intend to go for dynamic checking, it would be performance heavy as you would need to keep track of all characters till the last delimiter and on each keystroke you would need to validate the two checks - number and length of total word < 5

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation:

Markup

```
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="comma separated values"></textarea>
    <span id="msg"></span>
    <br>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Script

```
     function isValid() {
        var value = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        var values = value.split(',');
        if(values.length > 0 && values.length < 5){
             for(var i =0;i<values.length;i++);{
                if(parseInt(values[i]) === NaN) return false;
             }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function submit(){
        if(isValid()){
            document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Valid";
         //submit the form    
        } else {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "not a valid input";
        }
    }
```